# creating a class file : one column abstract in two column article

Tags: two-column, document-classes, article, abstract

I am trying to create a latex **class** file, the thing i want to do is to span the abstract and keywords to two columns like the one in example below. I need help in modifying the code in **class** file to look like this ...

[image: two-column abstract]

The class file;

```
\ProvidesClass{surjtemplate}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper,10pt,twocolumn}{article}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{
  \normalfont
  \list{}{
    \labelwidth0pt
    \leftmargin0pt \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \listparindent\parindent \itemindent0pt
    \parsep0pt
    \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax}
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries\abstractname\enspace --] \small}{\endlist}

\newcommand{\keywordsname}{Keywords}
\newenvironment{keywords}{
  \normalfont
  \list{}{
    \labelwidth0pt
    \leftmargin0pt \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \listparindent\parindent \itemindent0pt
    \parsep0pt
    \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax}
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries\keywordsname:] \small}{\endlist}


\makeatletter
\makeatother
\endinput
```

The tex file;

```
\documentclass{surjtemplate}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title of the paper}

\author{Author Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[10]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Production, Executable, Architecture
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}

\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/journal-article